# Regex split string по закрывающему тегу "/>"

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

подскажите, пожалуйста можно ли применить `Regex.Split` по закрывающему тегу `/>`.
К примеру, имеется строка:

```html
<area shape="poly" coords="464, 1415, 554, 1414, 741, 1415, 786, 1426, 792, 1464, 706, 1481, 592, 1477, 499, 1475, 438, 1457, 448, 1426" /><area shape="rect" coords="154, 581, 791, 694" />
```

, чтобы на выходе получить массив строк на c#:

```
[0]:"<area shape="poly" coords="464, 1415, 554, 1414, 741, 1415, 786, 1426, 792, 1464, 706, 1481, 592, 1477, 499, 1475, 438, 1457, 448, 1426" />"
[1]:"<area shape="poly" coords="414, 1215, 154, 1414, 441, 1415, 786, 426, 792, 1464, 706, 1481, 592, 1477, 499, 1475, 438, 1457, 448, 1426" />"
```

Пробовал:

```
const string pattern = "<area.*?>";           
string[] result = Regex.Split(areaCodeHtml, pattern).ToArray();
```

не работает

Comment: `"<area[^>]*>"`? https://regex101.com/r/IDu27S/2

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если это HTML, то гораздо лучше использовать специально предназначенный для этого парсер.

```cs
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    string html = @"<area shape=""poly"" coords=""464, 1415, 554, 1414, 741, 1415, 786, 1426, 792, 1464, 706, 1481, 592, 1477, 499, 1475, 438, 1457, 448, 1426"" /><area shape=""rect"" coords=""154, 581, 791, 694"" />";
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//area");
    foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.OuterHtml);
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
<area shape="poly" coords="464, 1415, 554, 1414, 741, 1415, 786, 1426, 792, 1464, 706, 1481, 592, 1477, 499, 1475, 438, 1457, 448, 1426">
<area shape="rect" coords="154, 581, 791, 694">
```

Можно сразу нужный аттрибут получить

```cs
foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["shape"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["coords"].Value);
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
poly
464, 1415, 554, 1414, 741, 1415, 786, 1426, 792, 1464, 706, 1481, 592, 1477, 499, 1475, 438, 1457, 448, 1426
rect
154, 581, 791, 694
```