# Не могу правильно составить Regex-паттерн

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Мне необходимо выбрать все a-теги в строке, но, вместо этого выбираются все как один

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Этот сайт](http://regexstorm.net/tester) служит для проверки Regex в C#

**Исходники:**

- **Паттерн:** `<a(.*)>(.*)</a>`
- **Текст:** `Alex оставил <a href=\"https://freelancehunt.com/my/reviews#project-859783\">отзыв</a> о проекте <a href=\"https://freelancehunt.com/project/dobavit-funktsiyu-vremeni-prilozheniyu/859783.html\">Добавить функцию времени к приложению</a>`

Comment: `<a[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>`

Comment: Вам что именно нужно, HTML распарсить или регулярку призумать, какая перед вами задача? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1257970/373567 а вообще есть помощнее сайт https://regex101.com

Comment: @aepot просто найти а-теги в строке

Comment: @InDevX огромное спасибо!

Comment: [Жадная и ленивая квантификация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения#Жадная_и_ленивая_квантификация)

Answer (score -1):

Спасибо @InDevX за решение и @AlexanderPetrov за ссылку на статью!

- Решение: `<a[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>`
- Статья: [Жадная и ленивая квантификация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%96%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)